# Laravel change pagination data

Tags: laravel

My Laravel pagination output is like laravel pagination used to be, but I need to change the data array for each object.
My output is:

[image: Output]

As you can see, the data object has 2 items, which I need to change.

My code is:

```
$items = $this->items()
        ->where('position', '=', null)
        ->paginate(15);
```

Which returns the user items with pivot table, but I don't like the way the pivot table is shown in the JSON, so I decided to change the items and organize each item with the pivot before the item.

For this purpose, I tried to use `foreach`

```
foreach ($items->data as $item)
        {

        }
```

which giving my an error, for a reason I don't know:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$data"
status_code: 500
```

Any help?

Comment: Tried $items as $item?

Comment: A modern approach to this would be to use resources: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources

Answer (score 144):

The paginator's items is a collection. You can grab it and transform the data like so:

```
$paginator = $this->items()->where('position', '=', null)->paginate(15);
$paginator->getCollection()->transform(function ($value) {
    // Your code here
    return $value;
});
```

If you are familiar with `tap` helper here is the snippet that does exact same.

```
$paginator = tap($this->items()->where('position', '=', null)->paginate(15),function($paginatedInstance){
    return $paginatedInstance->getCollection()->transform(function ($value) {
        return $value;
    });
});
```

We can't chain method [getCollection](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php#L622) to paginator instance because `AbstractPaginator` will return paginator's underlying collection. so the paginator instance will be transformed to Collection. So fix that we can use tap helper.

Comment: thanks, bro! and don't forget to return the modified data at the bottom.

Comment: You loose pagination data in this way

Comment: @realtebo. Works fine in Lara 8

Comment: @realtebo Just return $paginator which contains the pagination data.

Answer (score 53):

If you'd like to keep items paginated:

```php
        $itemsPaginated = $this->items()
             ->paginate(15);

        $itemsTransformed = $itemsPaginated
            ->getCollection()
            ->map(function($item) {
                return [
                    'id' => $item->id,
                ];
        })->toArray();

        $itemsTransformedAndPaginated = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
            $itemsTransformed,
            $itemsPaginated->total(),
            $itemsPaginated->perPage(),
            $itemsPaginated->currentPage(), [
                'path' => \Request::url(),
                'query' => [
                    'page' => $itemsPaginated->currentPage()
                ]
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I think this should be the accepted answer. Mainly because pagination functionality will continue to work in your views and you can still call functions such as "appends" and "links" in your blade files. These functions won't be available if you are getting a Collection passed to your blade views.

Comment: @hellovoid , Great Answer , You have saved my day :)

Comment: Best answer ever!

Comment: I suggest to remove `->toArray()` after transormation, to keep unaltered the object kind of the items. I explain: the paginator has a Collection as 'items'; if your use `toArray()`, the new Paginator works, but in the view you will not be able to access items attributes using object notation

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: You should use `'query' => \Request::query()`

Comment: I'm using `with('countries')`, with the result `'country' => [ 'country_id => 10, 'countryname' => 'Australia']`, how to get that `countryname` in map?

Comment: This helped me because it taught me how to create a LengthAwarePaginator from scratch, useful for when creating highly customized cases such as when wanting the items to be groupedBy something - I want to keep the meta info in-tact, but only the items are grouped

Comment: Laravel 8.9.0 has added the `through` method, which will keep the items paginated. `$itemsPaginated->through(function ($item) { return ['id' => $item->id ]; });` See my answer.

Answer (score 46):

There is a `setCollection` method for such purpose.

```
$items = Model::paginate(10);

$updatedItems = $items->getCollection();

// data manipulation
// ...

$items->setCollection($updateItems);
```

From the source code of `/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php`

```
/**
* Set the paginator's underlying collection.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $collection
* @return $this
*/
public function setCollection(Collection $collection)
{
    $this->items = $collection;

    return $this;
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php#L566)

Comment: this does not update other vital properties like `total` and `lastPage`, so it breaks pagination.

Comment: @user3803848 yeah you only want to update the collection for those data based on the current pagination data. Why do you want to change the total and lastPage?

Answer (score 6):

Laravel 8.9.0 has [added](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/34657) the `through` method to `AbstractPaginator`.
It transforms each item in the slice of items using a callback, and keeps the items paginated.

```
$paginator = $this->items()->where('position', '=', null)->paginate(15);
$paginator->through(function ($value) {
    // Your code here
    return $value;
});
```

The source code:

```
/**
 * Transform each item in the slice of items using a callback.
 *
 * @param  callable  $callback
 * @return $this
 */
public function through(callable $callback)
{
    $this->items->transform($callback);

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sample Example :

```
    $franchiseData=[ 'id'=>1 ,'name'=>'PAnkaj'];
    $models = $bookingsQuery->paginate(10);
    $models->setCollection(collect($franchiseData));
    return  $models;
```

> Note that  **$models->setCollection(collect($franchiseData))**; you have to use collect() else you will get error.

Answer (score 2):

I could make shorter way. This returns edited `$array` instead of simple `$paginated`. This example modify file names.
This [doc](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html) was useful for me.

```
    $paginated=$query->paginate(12);
    $array=$paginated->toArray();
    foreach ($array['data'] as $r=>$record) {
        $array['data'][$r]->gif=$array['data'][$r]->gif.".gif";
    }
    return $array;
```

Comment: Not if you want to keep the pagination fields

Answer (score 2):

```
getCollection
```

is one way to get the items. Another way is to use this
For ex- Assuming, `user` doesn't have `name` param and only have `first_name` and `last_name`

```
$userPaginatedData = User::paginate(15);
$users = $userPaginatedData->items();

foreach($users as $user) {
   $user->name = $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
}


return $userPaginatedData;
```

Now in the `data` key, you would see that each `user` has `name` param with it.

Answer (score 1):

-Laravel 5.4

```
// example update column "photo" 
// from "/path/to/photo.png" 
// to "abc.com/path/to/photo.png"
foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $path = $item->photo;

  // Remove 
  $item->offsetUnset("photo");

  // Set
  $item->offsetSet("photo", url($path));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel `AbstractPaginator` has methods [setCollection()](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.html#method_setCollection) and [getCollection()](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.html#method_getCollection)

```php
<?php

$itemsPaginated = $this->items()->paginate(15);
$itemsPaginated->setCollection(
    $itemsPaginated->getCollection()->transform(function ($item) {
       // Your code here
       return $item;
    })
)
```

Comment: I use filter() instead of transform, and it works:
  
    getCollection()->filter(function ($item) {
       // Your code here
       return $item;
    })

Answer (score 0):

This is your paginated items...

```
$items = $this->items()
        ->where('position', '=', null)
        ->paginate(15);
```

I am using Laravel 8, can simply use `each`

```
$items->each(function ($item) {
 // your code here
 $item->custom_data = calcSomeData(); // sample
});
```

It does the same as this...

```
$items->getCollection()->transform(function ($item) {
 // your code here
 $item->custom_data = calcSomeData(); // sample
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8+

```
$paginator = tap($this->items()->where('position', '=', null)->paginate(15), 
function ($paginatorInstance) {
    return $paginatedInstance->through(function ($value) {
    return $value;
});
    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

$itemsPaginated = $this->items()->paginate(15);

$itemsPaginated = json_encode($itemsPaginated);

foreach ($itemsPaginated->data as $key => $item) {
    $results->data[$key]; //Modify
}

$itemsPaginated = json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This will make loose all the information about pagination, eg: current_page, total pages...

Answer (score -11):

you have to use below code in your blade

```
{!! $items->render() !!}
```

Answer (score -11):

Ignore the pagination in laravel and hit the normal data

```
foreach ($items as $item)
{

}
```