# Laravel 7.0 pagination not working in method chain

Tags: php, eloquent, pagination, laravel-7

Here i am using method chaining on `Laravel Eloquent model (User)` with pagination,but after calling method `each` pagination stop working.
Is this behaviour expected or i am missing something. there noting mentioned about this on official docs.

#### Works fine

```
User::paginate(10)
    ->appends(request()->all());
```

#### Output

```
{
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "user@email.com",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "two@email.com",
      },
    ],
    "current_page": 1,
    "first_page_url": "//localhost/users?page=1",
    "last_page": 5,
    "last_page_url": "//localhost/users?page=5",
    "next_page_url": "//localhost/users?page=2",
    "path": "//localhost/users",
    "per_page": 10,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "total": 50
  }
```

But problem arrives when i call `each() method on it`

#### Not working

```
User::paginate(10)
    ->appends(request()->all())
    ->each(function ($user) {
        $user['someAttribute'] = 'value';
        return $user;
    })
```

#### Output (pagination not working)

plain simple result only query records. (Omitted pagination info)

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "email": "user@email.com",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "two@email.com",
  },
]
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39342941/3121398

Comment: Thanks @enver-arslan that works perfect, I am not sure why i don't found this when i was googling this problem before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can retrieve the pagination properties after altering the `$items`. You'd have to convert the altered data into the `LengthAwarePaginator` object manually.

```php
        $users = User::paginate(15);
        
        $alteredUsers = $users->getCollection()
            ->each(function($user) {
                $user['someAttribute'] = 'value';
                return $user;
        });
        
        $newPaginatedUsers = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
            $alteredUsers,
            $users->total(),
            $users->perPage(),
            $users->currentPage(),
            [
                'path' => \Request::URL(), // optional
            ]
        )->appends(request()->all());
```

You can look at the source [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php) and have a better idea of how to build the object.

Comment: `getCollection() ` method helps lot and solved my problem. as well works great https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102841/laravel-change-pagination-data/39342941#39342941 which is mentioned by @enver-arslan.

Answer (score 0):

Create an accessor:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function getSomeAttributeAttribute()
    {
        return 'value';
    }
}

$users = User::paginate(10)->appends(request()->all());
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json